# Configuration for local wordpress development using docker

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, docker

I'm new to Wordpress development (and especially Apache web server configuration) and I'm having trouble configuring and understanding the configuration for a local Wordpress environment using Docker.

I expose ports `8080` and `443` from the Wordpress docker image.

```
ports:
  - 8080:80
  - 443:443
```

It runs, connects to the database and is available at `http://localhost:8080`.

The urls in the database (local copy of production db) point to `https://example.com` and I therefore get quite a lot of CORS errors for scripts and images etc. All the links also point to the production site and I am thus unable to navigate the local version of the site.

How should I configure the `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` file in order to be able to:

1. Run the site on localhost:8080 without being redirected to `https://example.com` on every link I click.
2. Run the site at https://localhost (configure redirects over https)

Thirdly I would also like to understand what does `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` and `define('WP_HOME', 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` actually do, i.e. what happens internally when this is set and how should I configure this correctly in my case.

It doesn't really help my understanding that `WP_SITEURL` points to where the site is located and `WP_HOME` is where the user points his browser to when accessing your site.

Also how does `<VirtualHost>...</VirtualHost>` fit into this, can this help?

I would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction to understand the core principles better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the mysql database using phpmyadmin or any other tool you like. Then go to 'wp_options' table and change values of options 'siteurl' & 'home' to "localhost:8080"

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick.  So why does setting siteurl and home in the wp-config.php to localhost:8080 not work. I read that it should override the options in the db when present?

Comment: I think defining siteurl and home in wp-config.php does not replace these variables present in database, changing these two things in the database is the must thing. Most probably these variables in wp-config.php are used for multi-site wordpress and not in single site.

Comment: Also, if this resolves the issue then mark it as correct answer.